# Application crash issue in iPhone 4s

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using web services and location service in my application. My app is working fine on other devices but crashing on iPhone 4s. This problem has occurred after updating my XCode to XCode5. The Crash logs are as follows:

```
Date/Time:           2013-10-13 00:34:29.988 +1000
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.2 (11A501)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x2d849f4e 0x37c226aa 0x2d849c64 0x2ea11b24 0x6344a 0x2ffbf5fe 0x3006a8fc 0x3006a812 0x30069dee 0x30069b18 0x30069888 0x30069820 0x2ffbb01e 0x2fc44246 0x2fc3fa56 0x2fc3f8e8 0x2fc3f2fa 0x2fc3f10a 0x2ffb333e 0x2d8151d0 0x2d812b74 0x2d812eb6 0x2d77dce2 0x2d77dac6 0x3249e27e 0x3001fa3c 0x5eb0e 0x3812aab2)

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381e11fc 0x381ce000 + 78332
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3824aa2e 0x38247000 + 14894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x38191ff8 0x38148000 + 303096
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x374c0cd2 0x374c0000 + 3282
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x374d96e0 0x374c0000 + 104160
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37c2291e 0x37c1a000 + 35102
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x374d71c4 0x374c0000 + 94660
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x374d6d28 0x374c0000 + 93480
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37c227f2 0x37c1a000 + 34802
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2d77dd58 0x2d776000 + 32088
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2d77dac6 0x2d776000 + 31430
11  GraphicsServices                0x3249e27e 0x32496000 + 33406
12  UIKit                           0x3001fa3c 0x2ffb0000 + 457276
13  CashBackApp                     0x0005eb0e 0x59000 + 23310
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3812aab4 0x38129000 + 6836

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381ce83c 0x381ce000 + 2108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3810f220 0x38104000 + 45600
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3810efa6 0x38104000 + 44966

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381ceaf4 0x381ce000 + 2804
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3810d428 0x38104000 + 37928
2   CoreLocation                    0x2dd00c88 0x2dcfe000 + 11400
3   CoreLocation                    0x2dd0564a 0x2dcfe000 + 30282
4   CoreLocation                    0x2dd31ba8 0x2dcfe000 + 211880
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x382573aa 0x38253000 + 17322
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x3825593e 0x38253000 + 10558
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3810fd42 0x38104000 + 48450
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3810c256 0x38104000 + 33366
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3810ff8c 0x38104000 + 49036
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x3810c256 0x38104000 + 33366
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3810c096 0x38104000 + 32918
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3810c256 0x38104000 + 33366
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x3810c096 0x38104000 + 32918
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x3810cd12 0x38104000 + 36114
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x3810cf88 0x38104000 + 36744
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38247dbc 0x38247000 + 3516
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38247c80 0x38247000 + 3200

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381e1c7c 0x381ce000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38247dc6 0x38247000 + 3526
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38247c80 0x38247000 + 3200

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381cea8c 0x381ce000 + 2700
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381ce888 0x381ce000 + 2184
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2d8147c6 0x2d776000 + 649158
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2d812eec 0x2d776000 + 642796
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2d77dce2 0x2d776000 + 31970
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2d77dac6 0x2d776000 + 31430
6   Foundation                      0x2e1b7492 0x2e15f000 + 361618
7   Foundation                      0x2e22ce22 0x2e15f000 + 843298
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38249c1a 0x38247000 + 11290
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38249b8a 0x38247000 + 11146
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38247c8c 0x38247000 + 3212

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381e1c7c 0x381ce000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38247dc6 0x38247000 + 3526
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38247c80 0x38247000 + 3200

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381e1c7c 0x381ce000 + 81020
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38247dc6 0x38247000 + 3526
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38247c80 0x38247000 + 3200

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x381e1440 0x381ce000 + 78912
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2d818688 0x2d776000 + 665224
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38249c1a 0x38247000 + 11290
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38249b8a 0x38247000 + 11146
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38247c8c 0x38247000 + 3212

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3a05918c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27daa594
    r8: 0x16d0df20    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x40340000     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27daa588      lr: 0x3824aa33      pc: 0x381e11fc
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: which iOS version ? try using Exception break point Or Symbolicating your crash report

Comment: Are you sure this is actually running on the iPhone 4s? This seems like you plugged in your iPhone 4s but then it ran on the default option, the xcode simulator.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on unless you post a symbolicated crash report. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Comment: I'm getting an error while symbolising my crash report. atos cannot load symbols for the file MyApp.app/MyApp for architecture armv7.